# Save function is cropping strings - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am saving some strings into database (mysql), but laravel always saves this for example "Dru" instead of "Društvo". How can I resolve this? Its cropping string at point where is character with caron. If I manually save string and then fetch it laravel correctly displays it but if I write same string in view file I just get �. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure the database charset/coallition is `UTF-8`.
2. On the page you insert these russian characters ( the form, textarea ), make sure the encoding is `UTF-8`, by setting Content-Type to `text/html;` `charset=utf-8.` Enter in russian text directly to the form input.
3. On the processing page that handles this form, which inserts it into the database, make sure to do `SET NAMES` `utf8` so it's stored as UTF-8 **before** you insert the data, in a separate query beforehand.
4. When you render the content from the database in a view, make sure the Content-Type is `text/html; charset=utf-8`.

Make sure that the content-type is **not** windows-1251 or iso-8859-1/latin1. Make sure the database charset/coallition is NOT ISO-8859-1/Latin1.

**Second way to store character in mysql:**

Try calling `mysql_set_charset('utf8');` after connecting to the database. I think it's similar to executing a `SET NAMES` query, but since the PHP manual says using that function over a `SET NAMES` query is recommended, I'd try it.

At last,
Also, when you display your content, you could try Also, when you display your content, you could try `echo htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');`

I had same problem in laravel but I figure out this way.let me know if any query.

Comment: Thanks for helping. All those settings were fine, and after many tests i found out that phpstorm encoding in project was wrong (i just don't know why project encoding override file-encoding).

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your `app/config/database.php`

`'charset'   => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',` inside the mysql array.

If it is already there, make sure your table columns are set to utf8_unicode_ci.

Thank you